# How do you launch Launchpad or the Mission Control (Exposè) from the Mac command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

Prior to Catalina (macOS 10.15), one was able to launch the Launchpad (F3 button) or the Mission Control (F4 button on an Apple keyboard) from the command line using `/Applications/Launchpad.app/Contents/MacOS/Launchpad` or `/Applications/Mission\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\ Control`. With Catalina, it’s not possible anymore.

**Is there an alternative?** The goal is to map my regular F3 and F4 keys to such a command, so that I can use a non-Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to map my regular F3 and F4 keys to such a command, so that I can use a non-Apple keyboard.

You can accomplish that goal without invoking those features from the command line. In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, there are categories on the left for "Launchpad & Dock" and "Mission Control". In the respective category, there's an entry on the right for "Show Launchpad" and "Mission Control". You can assign any keyboard combination you like (including F3 or F4) to those features.

Comment: Ken's answer is correct and will work for most people.  However if you have a keyboard that does not have standard F keys like the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 where F1 is marked as "Help", then this will not work even with F lock.  In this case a combination of Better Touch Tool and USB Overdrive will work.  Set a keyboard shortcut in Better Touch Tool for Mission Control and in USB Overdrive program a macro for the Help/F1 key to type same shortcut.

Comment: i would like to accomplish something similar: i would like to open the launchpad if i press CMD, but with the keyboard shortcuts in settings i can only do CMD+"another key". i come from a gnome background and mainly work with gnome on linux. i know my macbook as a sexy trackpad, i love it, but this one i would like to solve my cmd on the keyboard